# How do you get Jenkins to count the build run as pass when failed testng tests are retried and passes?

Tags: java, testng, jenkins, mobile-automation

How do you get Jenkins to count the build run as pass when failed TestNG tests are retried and passes?

**Description:**

```
I have two tests that ran. Test1 passed, but Test2 failed then on retry it passed.
```

**Actual Results:**

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0.
```

**Expected Results:**

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

or

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1 (Skipped for retry tests)
```

**Code:**

```
    public class TestRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private static int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 1; 
    //Only works for value of 1; Anything more than that causes 
    infinite retries for the same test even when it passes.

    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RETRY_COUNT);

    public boolean isRetryAvailable() {
        return (count.intValue() > 0);
    }

    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        boolean retry = false;
        if (isRetryAvailable()) {
            Reporter.log("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", " + (MAX_RETRY_COUNT - count.intValue() + 1) + " out of " + MAX_RETRY_COUNT, true);
            retry = true;
            count.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return retry;
    }
}

  public class TestListenerSupport extends TestListenerAdapter {
  TestUtilities testUtil = new TestUtilities();

@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result){
    //Handle events before test start
    //Obtain specific annotation info from test methods
    Stable stable = 
  result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
  .getAnnotation(Stable.class);
   Maturing maturing = 
  result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
  .getAnnotation(Maturing.class);
   Preflight preFlight = 
   result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
   .getAnnotation(Preflight.class);
      if (stable != null){
           Reporter.log("Annotation is set to STABLE! for '" + 
    result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "'.", true);
      }
      if (maturing != null){
           Reporter.log("Annotation is set to MATURING! for '" + 
    result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "'.", true);
     }
      if (preFlight != null){
           Reporter.log("Annotation is set to PREFLIGHT! for '" + 
    result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "'.", true);
    }
}


  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result){

      if (result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer() != null) {
            TestRetry retryAnalyzer = 
     (TestRetry)result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer();

            if(retryAnalyzer.isRetryAvailable()) {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
            } else {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
            }

            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
        }
}

@Override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result){

    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped invoked! " + result.getThrowable().toString(),true);
    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped Exception Message: " + result.getThrowable().getMessage(),true);
    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped Exception Cause: " + result.getThrowable().getCause(),true);
    Reporter.log("onTestSkipped Exception StackTrace: " + result.getThrowable().getStackTrace(), true);
    AppiumDriver driver = getDriverInstance(result);
    if(driver!=null){
        TestUtilities testUtil = new TestUtilities();
        try {
            testUtil.getScreenShot(driver, result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "_Skipped");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Reporter.log("Killing appium driver instance",true);
        driver.quit();
    }
    else
        Reporter.log("onTestSkipped - null driver detected", true);
}

@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result){
    Map map = new HashMap();
    //get the testcase IDs from input xml file used for creating a test run in TestRail
    Map<String,String> test_case_id = result.getMethod().getXmlTest().getAllParameters();
    String test_name = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    testUtil.writeResult("1", test_case_id.get(test_name));

}
```